# Why is there error in line 5 when i am converting it into integer and then adding

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting

I am getting error on line 5 as

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

when i am converting string into integer before adding

I have tried it by checking the code but can't find any mistake by myself.

```py
def dig_pow(n, p):
    k=str(n)
    sum=0
    for i in k:
        sum+=int(i)**p+i
    if sum%n==0:
        return sum/n
    return -1
```

I Expected the Function to work and give me some output but There is error on line 5.
So,what am i doing wrong?

Comment: the last `i` is a string in the line `sum+=int(i)**p+i`. (and you should not use `sum` as a variable; you are shadowing the a built-in function).

Comment: `sum+=int(i)**p+int(i)`

Comment: why using string `k`, use range with integer k.

Comment: You can use `for i in (int(x) for x in k):` to do the conversion early .

Comment: `sum()` is a builtin, you should avoid using it as a variable name if possible

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you are trying to perform an arithmetic operation (+) between an integer(`int`) and a string (`str`). Of course, `1 + a` is invalid and this is happening because every item `i` in `k` is a string due to this string conversion: `k=str(n)`. The following example illustrates this:

```
In [6]: k = str(5)

In [8]: for i in k:
   ...:     print("I am an item in {} and my type is {}.".format(i,type(i)))
   ...:
I am an item in 5 and my type is <class 'str'>.
```

But what you are trying to achieve is loop over integers from 1 to n and for that you don't require an intermediate variable `k` and certainly not a string-type variable if you are trying to perform arithmetic operations within the loop. However, you can cast the result to a string later, if you really want to.

Python provides a built-in `range` function that allows one to loop over a range of integers. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range). So, now we can run a loop from 1 to `n` and get our result:

```
In [1]: def dig_pow(n, p):
   ...:     result=0
   ...:     for i in range(1, n):
   ...:         result+=int(i)**p+i
   ...:     if result%n==0:
   ...:         return result/n
   ...:     return -1

In [3]: dig_pow(5, 7)
Out[3]: 3742.0

In [4]: dig_pow(7, 7)
Out[4]: 53826.0

In [5]: dig_pow(9, 0)
Out[5]: -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dig_pow(n, p):
    k = str(n)
    mySum = 0
    for i in k:
        mySum += int(i) ** p + int(i)
    if mySum%n == 0:
        return mySum/n
    return -1
```

dig_pow(3,2)

```
4.0
```

dig_pow(123,5)

```
-1
```

Comment: Thanks I understood my mistake actually I wasn't focusing on the other I.